# why some people use the notation $a \leq O(n)$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

When describing the algorithm complexity denoted by $c$, some people use $c \leq O(n)$ instead of  $c =O(n)$ to show complexity.  I cannot understand why they should use $\leq $?

Comment: With the usual definition big-Oh notation only implies an upper bound on the growth of an expression (here $c$ or $a$ per the title, depending on $n$), so you are right that these are equivalent.  Some author might prefer $\le$ to remind their reader that only an upper bound is promised, or even to emphasize that the sharpness of the bound is not yet shown.